# How do I interact with multiple sprites in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite

I am currently working on a game where I want to swipe the sprites left and right as they fall down from the top of the screen. However, I am only able to interact with the most recent sprite generated. All the other sprites I am unable to touch. I am unsure what the problem is but I would appreciate any help. Thanks! I will put the code below if any one is interested in seeing what I am taking about.

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

var sprite: SKSpriteNode!
var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()
var touching: Bool = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.999)
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2.0, y: frame.size.height)

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addMonster), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))

}

func addMonster() {

    sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2.0, y: frame.size.height)

    addChild(sprite)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if sprite.frame.contains(location) {
        touchPoint = location
        touching = true
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        touchPoint = location}
}



override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touching = false
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if touching {
        let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/60.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-sprite.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-sprite.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
    }
}
 }
```